# Tomcat Deadlock in Thread

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, tomcat7, deadlock

I am using Tomcat 7.0.42 for an application that uses websockets. If my application is under heavy load I get a deadlock in some of my threads that use websockets.

Is there a workaround for this problem, since I could not find a fix?

I use Atmpshere 2.0RC3 runtime-native.

Here is the relevant part of my thread dump. I used Samurai to detected the deadlocked threads.

```
     "Atmosphere-Shared-AsyncOp-267"   daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007efed8118000 nid=0x2eb5 waiting for monitor entry [0x00007efe798ca000]      java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)      at org.apache.catalina.websocket.WsOutbound.writeTextMessage(WsOutbound.java:165)      - waiting to lock <0x00000005ef4c6988> (a org.apache.catalina.websocket.WsOutbound)      
at org.atmosphere.container.version.TomcatWebSocket.write(TomcatWebSocket.java:49)      
at org.atmosphere.websocket.WebSocket.write(WebSocket.java:199)      
at org.atmosphere.websocket.WebSocket.write(WebSocket.java:168)   
   at org.atmosphere.websocket.WebSocket.write(WebSocket.java:40)     
 at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereResponse$2.write(AtmosphereResponse.java:574)      
at org.atmosphere.handler.AbstractReflectorAtmosphereHandler.onStateChange(AbstractReflectorAtmosphereHandler.java:169)      
at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster.invokeOnStateChange(DefaultBroadcaster.java:1027)   
   at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster.prepareInvokeOnStateChange(DefaultBroadcaster.java:1047)    
  at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster.executeAsyncWrite(DefaultBroadcaster.java:921)     
 at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster$3.run(DefaultBroadcaster.java:580)      - locked <
    0x00000005ef4b77f8> (a org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereResourceImpl)     
 at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)  
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)   
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)    
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)     
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)    
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)  


    "Atmosphere-Scheduler-2"   daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007efee9c77800 nid=0x257d waiting for monitor entry [0x00007efe831ef000]      java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)      
at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.completeLifecycle(AsynchronousProcessor.java:476)      - waiting to lock <0x00000005ef4b77f8> (a org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereResourceImpl)     
 at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.timedout(AsynchronousProcessor.java:437)      
at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor$AsynchronousProcessorHook.timedOut(AsynchronousProcessor.java:633)     
 at org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor.close(DefaultWebSocketProcessor.java:483)      
at org.atmosphere.container.TomcatWebSocketHandler.onClose(TomcatWebSocketHandler.java:80)      
at org.apache.catalina.websocket.StreamInbound.doOnClose(StreamInbound.java:222)      
at org.apache.catalina.websocket.WsOutbound.doWriteBytes(WsOutbound.java:423)      
at org.apache.catalina.websocket.WsOutbound.doWriteText(WsOutbound.java:442)      
at org.apache.catalina.websocket.WsOutbound.writeTextMessage(WsOutbound.java:174)      - locked <
    0x00000005ef4c6988> (a org.apache.catalina.websocket.WsOutbound)      
at org.atmosphere.container.version.TomcatWebSocket.write(TomcatWebSocket.java:49)      
at org.atmosphere.websocket.WebSocket.write(WebSocket.java:199)      
at org.atmosphere.websocket.WebSocket.write(WebSocket.java:168)      
at org.atmosphere.websocket.WebSocket.write(WebSocket.java:40)      
at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereResponse$2.write(AtmosphereResponse.java:574)      
at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereResponse.write(AtmosphereResponse.java:992)      
at org.atmosphere.interceptor.HeartbeatInterceptor$1$1.call(HeartbeatInterceptor.java:104)      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)      
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)      
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)     
 at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)     
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)     
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)  
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Comment: Which atmosphere version are you using?

Comment: @SzymonBiliński I use Atmpshere 2.0RC3 runtime-native

Comment: Both threads are waiting to lock `243f01c7` (`waiting to lock <...>`), but the thread that locked it (`locked <...>`) can not be seen on this. I think you should look after it (and may be include it in the question).

Comment: @Katona I updated my question with the threads that are deadlocked. I used Samurai to detect them. Does this helps you? Or may be this helps you: https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/issues/1264

Comment: @confile yes, that issue seems to be the same one, and I think it's problem with Atmosphere, I left a comment on github.

Comment: @thank you! May be you can help me with that issue too: http://serverfault.com/questions/536256/haproxy-502-bad-gateway

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat bug!!!
You need to update Tomcat to the latest version or configure like this:

Add in your web.xml:

```
  <init-param>
      <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.Broadcaster.writeTimeout</param-name>
      <param-value>VALUE</param-value>
  </init-param>
```

The VALUE is in milliseconds i suggest 20000 - 30000.